# Tableau Extract not found due to temporary storage location

Tags: tableau-api

I am relatively new to Tableau and may have encountered some data loss .. but let us proceed to see if there might be some means to salvage the data.

Upon re-loading a workbook after a couple of weeks of non use we can see reference to an Extract load attempt from a temporary (OS/X) location:

[image]

Now I had not realized that the Extract were not being saved with the `.twb` itself - and even less that it were in a `transient` disk location.

So .. is the data gone?  Secondarily - did I miss some step that would nudge me to save the extract to a non-volatile/non temporary location on disk?

Comment: Was this an extract against a database or a file-based data source like csv or Excel?

Comment: @SamM A `csv` file.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with file-based extracts as I am database extracts but I found a few references online that may help. Are you by chance using a twbx (packaged workbook) instead of the twb workbook file? With a twbx file, the extract ends up in a temporary folder and named like the one you have in the image.

Comment: yes it is .a .`.twbx` .  And now what do I do about it ..

Comment: Open the twbx in desktop, then do a Save As but save it as a twb instead of a packaged workbook. In theory, this ought to reset the extract to point to the original data location (not that temp one). With that info, you may be able to find the csv file on the computer of the person who last packaged the workbook.

Comment: @SamM That sounds like a reasonable idea. Will try that out when I get back to that computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your file location shows you are accessing file from temporary location and you are loading your workbook after a couple of week.

So may be your OS deleted your files.

Try to save your files in safe location rather then accessing from temporary location.

Comment: Yea - that's the point.   I was never consulted on the matter. Notice from the OP *and even less that it were in a transient disk location.*